# Calculate a quartic monic polynomial given that $P(1)=10,P(2)=20$ and $P(3)=30$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let

$$P(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are constants.

If $P(1)=10,P(2)=20$ and $P(3)=30$, then what is the value of $$\frac{P(12)+P(-8)}{10}$$

I tried substituting $x=1,2,3$ in $P(x)$ to get three linear equations in $a,b,c$ and $d$, but it ended up being quite difficult. 
$$a+b+c+d=9$$
$$8a+4b+2c+d=4$$
$$27a+9b+3c+d=-51$$

Is there a simpler method to this question?

Comment: Solve for $a,b,c$ in terms of $d$

Comment: Out of curiosity, what year is this question from?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I did not get you, this question was asked in a test I wrote recently

Comment: @Fasal123 The answer is a year from a couple of decades ago. It can be a coincidence, though. It is quite common in contest mathematics to engineer questions so that the answer is the current year. I was just trying to figure out whether that had happened here.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta No, I just think it is a coincidence

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Define $Q(x) = P(x) - 10x$, then$$
P(1) = 10,\ P(2) = 20,\ P(3) = 30 \Longrightarrow Q(1) = Q(2) = Q(3) = 0.
$$
Since $\deg Q = 4$ and $Q$ is monic, there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that$$
Q(x) = (x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)(x - x_0).
$$
Therefore,\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} P(12) + P(-8)\\
&= Q(12) + Q(-8) + 40\\
&= 11 × 10 × 9 × (12 - x_0) + (-9) × (-10) × (-11) × (-8 - x_0) +40\\
&= 11 × 10 × 9 × (12 - x_0) + 11 × 10 × 9 × (8 + x_0) +40\\
&= 11 × 10 × 9 × ((12 - x_0) + (8 + x_0)) +40\\
&= 11 × 10 × 9 × 20 +40\\
&=19840.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 11):

$$P(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-\alpha) + 10 x$$

$$P(12) = 990(12- \alpha) + 120 \tag1$$

$$P(-8) = -990(-8 - \alpha) - 80 \tag 2$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$P(12) + P(-8) = 19840 \implies \cfrac{P(12) + P(-8)}{10} = 1984$$